# Global CSS using flex layout

Tags: angular, responsive-design, angular-flex-layout

I am creating angular 2 application with angular material and for responsiveness I am using angular flex-layout library. But while working with angular flex layout I came to know that for each page I need to modify the CSS as per requirement. 
As my applications are having almost 60 pages, Its too complicate to redesign all the pages with flex syntax.

So I need to ask,

1. Can I create Global CSS using Flex-layout so efforts for modifying each page will reduce?.
2. Can I use another library for responsiveness which will be easier than flex layout?
3. What should I use for responsiveness as well as fluid page structure in angular 2 application?

Please any one suggest me the correct way to design web application in Angular 2.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, some styles have to be global for example layout structural classes like Bootstrap or Flexbox etc. Otherwise you will repeat .css classes in many components.
2. Bootstrap 3 is very popular and despite if some developers prefer it or not it is used by so many devs and projects so it is very easy to maintain, solve problems and new devs that will join the project can easily maintain and write new code.
3. I would suggest flexbox or bootstrap 3. This looks promising http://flexboxgrid.com/ also.

If you have some questions please feel free to ask :)

Comment: But currently I am having different classes on different pages . So how to modify it to Global CSS?

Comment: Which one is better Flex-layout or Bootstrap? Both I dont know. I need to study both.

Comment: I would start with bootstrap since it is using older but more stable CSS techniques. Flexbox it is just a new way of achieving the same results. You could start with that if you like it is up to you. Most devs know Boostrap. I didn't understand exactly what is the problem "But currently I am having different classes on different pages . So how to modify it to Global CSS?" can u please explain a bit more and maybe post some code if it is needed ?